# How to Parse through nsXml Parser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxml, xml-attribute

i am very new to iphone Development and i am asked to use nsxml parser to parse xml from a google api. i have parsed another url which has xml but i am not able to parse google's because it is using id's to store data rather than inside tag. i.e.

```
<forecast_information>
    <city data="Anaheim, CA"/>
    <postal_code data="anaheim,ca"/>
    <latitude_e6 data=""/>
    <longitude_e6 data=""/>
    <forecast_date data="2010-03-11"/>
    <current_date_time data="2010-03-12 07:06:32 +0000"/>
    <unit_system data="US"/>
</forecast_information>
```

Can somebody help me that how can i parse the attribute inside the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name and value of a NSXMLNode are given by methods [name](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIHAJFF) and [stringValue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIBGIDA) respectively. For an attribute node, these are the attibute name and value.

The attributes of a NSXMLElement are given by method [attributes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLElement_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002407-BBCBAACE), or a particular attribute can be accessed by name with method [attributeForName:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLElement_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002407-BBCFGFBI).

```
NSXMLElement *forecast_information;

for( NSXMLElement *el in [forecast_information children] ) {
    NSString *name = [el name];
    NSString *value = @"";
    if ([el attributeForName: @"data"]) {
      value = [[el attributeForName: @"data"] stringValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you would need to use NSXMLDocument to get NSXMLNodes (including NSXMLElements). NSXMLParser, which is what the questioner is using, will not give you any such objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody help me that how can i parse the attribute inside the tag [using NSXMLParser].

In your parser delegate, implement [the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:). The attributes will be in the dictionary that the parser gives you in that last argument.